# A minimum reputation of 50 to comment - why?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

If someone can please clarify, I don't get the minimum reputation of **50** required to comment on someone else's answer or question. This is simply too high for new users. I have lost track of about 10-20 questions/answers which I wanted to comment (with a comment as simple as 'please cite sources') - which I can no way remember and go back to do after my reputation has gone up.

Comment: Its more of SE policy then hindusim.se's , and its discussed again and again over main meta [example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51408/remove-reputation-minimum-to-comment)

Answer (score 4):

It's not just Hinduism.SE is having such a rule, its the same across StackExchange network. Coming to your question that why such a rule is because new users tend to chat is because we want don't want spam from new users.

It might happen that few people can make fake accounts and start spamming across the site which is not only bad for the website but it will be tough for the users and moderators to control and keep a watch for that all the time.

Indeed we may lose some valuable information a new user might want to contribute in a comment but chances of this is too low. It's like 1 in 10 comments might be useful.

---

Coming to the second part of your question which says *I have lost track of about 10-20 questions/answers which I wanted to comment* so for this we do provide a feature which is called "Mark as Favorite" by clicking on the star besides the question. This will not only remind you for commenting but you will also get notifications for whatever activity is carried on that question.

I hope this solves your doubt. Also you have 51 reputation now so happy commenting.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Not every question/answer I read or comment is my favorite, so "Mark as Favorite" is only a workaround not a _feature_ designed for _come back later to comment when your reputation is up_. We have another _feature_ for the same purpose it's called _browser history_ ;-)

Comment: _It's like 1 in 10 comments might be useful_ I wouldn't make any such assumptions having read others questions/clarifications/suggestions to improve the answers in comments including some of the mods' on Hinduism.SE.

Comment: @sv. Again, these stats are from StackExchange where they collect the data of how many general comments are deleted by moderators, I will find a link for you

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead Here you go

Comment: That is, in my opinion, not a good system because those who cannot comment will post an answer. A bad comment is much better than a bad answer.